# TF31002 error when trying to view test results on TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I am using Microsoft Test Manager to run coded UI tests.  The test results are listed on our TFS 2013 server.  If I show the test details pane on the TFS server and double click on the results, it attempts to launch MTM 2013, but I get the error below.  The problem seems to be that it is trying to use the url - http://server:8080/tfs/defaultcollection to connect, but should be using http://server:8080/defaultcollection.  I have searched trying to find out where to change the TFS url to be the correct one, but have not had any luck finding a solution yet.  Can anyone offer some help as to where this can be changed.

The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

```
(mtm.exe, PID 5608, Thread 7) Exception: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException
    Message: TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: http://server:8080/tfs/defaultcollection.
Team Foundation Server Url: http://server:8080/tfs/defaultcollection.
```

Possible reasons for failure include:

- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
- The Team Foundation Server is offline.
- The password has expired or is incorrect.

Technical information (for administrator):

```
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
    Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureProviderConnected()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureAuthenticated()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.Runtime.AuthenticateServerHelper.EnsureAuthenticated(TfsConnection server, Boolean allowPrompt)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.Runtime.AuthenticateServerHelper.CheckServer(String serverUri, Boolean checkAvailability, Boolean isProjectCollection, TfsConnection& server, Exception& lastException, Boolean canPromptOnAuthorizationFailure)
    BaseExceptionMessage: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
    InnerException: System.Net.WebException
    InnerException Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
    InnerException Stack Trace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequestAndGetResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest, WebException& webException)
    InnerExceptionBaseExceptionMessage: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table

Answer (score 1):

The default TFS (on-premises) url should be something as below:

`http://ServerName:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/ProjectName`

If the MTM try to use the url - `http://server:8080/tfs/defaultcollection` to get the test result, this should be the right operation.

Suggest you first [check the tfs url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380739(v=vs.120).aspx) configured in **MTM**. Make sure your TFS server URL is right.

[image]

Besides, suggest you try to create a new test and view the new generated test result from TFS web portal. Check if you could view the result successfully. And double check which url it is using.

You could also try to change the web url in TFS Admin Console to the default format. How to please refer this [blog](https://www.tjopsta.net/2010/04/16/how-to-change-team-foundation-server-2010-urls-for-use-externally/).

Comment: I checked the url in MTM and it is correct.  I created a new test and ran it and attempted to view the results, but it is still going to the wrong url.  I think that I probably need to change it in the admin console.  I don't think that I have access to make the change, but I will try to get someone who does to make the change for me and reply back.  Thanks for your response.  I will post an update when I have one.

Comment: @hangelo If you decided to change the url. After you changed the url, also try to [clear TFS cahce](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) , and any update feel free to share here.

Comment: I am afraid not.  I am still waiting on my supervisor to change the url.  He has been out of the office traveling.